# Is this better to store system-defined credentials in a middleware layer or in custom settings?

Tags: integration, security, namedcredentials

For an outbound integration from Salesforce to External System, is this better to store system-defined credentials in a middleware layer or in `Custom Settings` or in `Static Resource`?

Is this secure to store it in `Custom Settings`?

Is this secure to store it in `Static Resource`?

Can Platform Encryption or Classic Encryption be used to provide security?

Answer (score 4):

The best way to store credentials for basic authentication is storing them in [Named Credentials](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=named_credentials_about.htm&type=5).

They provide the best security option here, since no one, including admin, cannot read the password from it.

However, in some cases this is not an option, if a dynamic endpoint should be used.

For ISV two additional options which support dynamic endpoint, are `Protected Custom Settings` and `Protected Custom Metadata`.

When ISV stores credentials in `Protected Custom Settings` or `Protected Custom Metadata`, subcriber clients cannot access these data but the Apex code from the managed package can.

For a unpackaged code, `Custom Settings` and `Static Resources` are not good option to store credentials, since every admin can read the values from them, which means this is not secure enough, so I think if there is a way to store credentials in a middle layer, it is better to use this option, if `Named Credential` cannot be used for any reason.

Platform Encryption doesn't affect the security settings of what users see.

Classic Encryption while having additional feature of Masking data, doesn't also provide the mechanism to hide the data from the users that aren't expected to see the data. Instead Field Level Security can be used to hide data stored in some fields from users, but since admins can see all fields and all data, this is not a way to securely store the credentials, because every admin can modify FLS to obtain the access to the field value and read it.

Comment: this is also covered in detail in [Securing Sensitive Data](https://developer.salesforce.com/wiki/secure_coding_storing_secrets)